# Dropdown Menu Not working in Firefox/Chrome

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

So lets just say i got it all to work on IE since its always IE that gives the problems.  But now the dropdown menu appears behind the content on other browsers like firefox and chrome.  All i did was remove the z-index in the #head div.

Website: http://www.stingrayimages.ca/

With Z-index: it breaks in IE 
Without it it fails in other browsers.

Anyway to fix the dropdown menu without adding z-index to the head div?

```
#head {
    position:relative;
    height: 140px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #FFF;
    filter:alpha(opacity=93);
    padding-top:20px;
    /* CSS3 standard */
    opacity:0.93;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px black;
}
```

Comment: An example link would be really helpful. Otherwise you could always use a conditional stylesheet to add the z-index in for IE.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer @amustill Sorry added website

Comment: @amustill i tried giving up and use a conditional stylesheet for the z-index but for some reason that doesnt work but i know the stylesheet is working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to lessen the opacity. The drop down is washing out when it is displayed over the images and that is making it look like it is behind the pictures.

Also, IE9 shows the same problem as Chrome and FireFox 4.

Comment: Holy crap it works! i guess im not able to have opacity there? The opacity was at 93% and that was too much?

Comment: Yes, 93% was way too much because the colors of the background are very similar to the color of the text in the drop down. If you want to have opacity, experiment with the setting. Do something like set it to 20% and see how it looks. Change it to 40% and see how it looks again. Keep doing that until you get an opacity value you are happy with.

Comment: Now only IE6 is giving me problems.

Comment: IE6 is the bane of all web designers. I'd suspect the position:relative of causing the problem. Check http://www.onderhond.com/blog/work/ie6-core-bug-fixing for fixes.

Answer (score 0):

Use z-index, just apply a higher z-index to the drop down elements that sit on top, or you could apply - z-index values to all content behind, either way works.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is put the z-index back and look up the IE fix for it.

Another thing to consider is the rendering order and tree structure of your html, as that influences what sits on top. http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/ this article explains it far better than I can.

If you are able to link an example of the site you're working on, it might make it easier for us to give a more specific answer.

Comment: Sorry i added a link to the website.